# Flask uploaded file size is not correct

Tags: python, flask

Why flask's uploaded file byte length is shorter than what it is actually? I'm seeing same behavior for several images.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = file.read()
        print(len(f))  # 45825
```

However,

```
f = skimage.io.imread('file.jpg')
len(f.tobytes())  # 1102080
```

Comment: len of byte vs file.read object

Comment: I think I misunderstand. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload an image using Flask, it reads the file's content as a bytestring, which represents the size of the compressed image file. However, when reading the image with skimage.io.imread('file.jpg'), it's read into a NumPy array, representing the uncompressed image data. So I think you're seeing the compression rate.

To compare the sizes fairly, you can convert the uploaded bytestring to a NumPy array without saving it to disk:

```py
import io
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        f = file.read()
        print(len(f))

        # Convert the bytestring to a NumPy array
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(f))
        image_np = np.array(image)
        print(len(image_np.tobytes()))
```

Comment: Thanks. It somehow didn't come up to my mind! I was seeing only jpg images.